# Uncaught SoapFault exception: HTTP Request Entity Too Large

Tags: php, wordpress, soap, woocommerce, fedex

I have a Wordpress site with WooCommerce and a FedEx plugin, everything works fine except for large orders where i get the error below:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Request Entity Too
Large in /html/wp-content/plugins/synmedia-woocommerce-shipping-
fedex/classes/class-syn-shipping-fedex.php:588 
Stack trace: #0 
[internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 
'https://wsbeta....', 'http://fedex.co...', 1, 0) #1 /html/wp-content
/plugins/synmedia-woocommerce-shipping-fedex/classes/class-
syn-shipping-fedex.php(588): 
SoapClient->__call('getRates', Array) #2 /html/wp-content/plugins
/synmedia-woocommerce-shipping-fedex/classes/class-syn-shipping-
fedex.php(588): SoapClient->getRates(Array) #3 /html/wp-content/plugins
/synmedia-woocommerce-shipping-fedex/syn-shipping/class-syn-shipping-
method.php(101): SYN_Shipping_Fedex->get_shipping_request(Array) #4 
/html/wp-conten in /html/wp-content/plugins/synmedia-woocommerce-
shipping-fedex/classes/class-syn-shipping-fedex.php on line 588
```

I have changed the following values in my PHP.ini file:

- max_file_uploads  = 50
- memory_limit  = 256M
- upload_max_filesize  = 256M
- post_max_size = 256M
- max_execution_time = 300

And still not working, i would appreciate some more ideas as i can't figure out why is erroring.

Comment: I'm thinking the limit is on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Check phpinfo to see what limits are set server-side. If you're using a shared provider it's highly likely that they are limiting the size of the POST. I've noticed woo plugins also have issue with low memory limits.